# Matlab mnrfit error "Inputs must be floats, namely single or double."

Tags: matlab, class

I have training data, that are `train_input` (`194x11` matrix) and `train_output` (`194x1` ordinal).

`class(train_input)` gives the result `double` and `class(train_output)` gives the result `ordinal`. I run them using `mnrfit` in Matlab. The command is basically

```
    [B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(train_output, train_input)
```

I get the error message:

```
Inputs must be floats, namely single or double.
```

I converted the ordinal output into double and this time the error is

```
If Y is a column vector, it must contain positive integer category numbers
```

I tried to make them categorical, bu this time I get

```
Creating an instance of the Abstract class 'categorical' is not allowed
```

The Matlab tutorial says that I keep them ordinal or categorical in order to apply `mnrfit`.

I also tried to run the examples myself, I get the last "categorical" error.

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not inputting floats. That's exactly what the error says. An ordinal is not a double or single, therefore it does not work.

[This](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html) page on the documentation shows examples and as far as I can see you need doubles for both `X` and `Y`. Try running the examples yourself and check the classes of their inputs.

Comment: I converted the ordinal output into double and this time the error is "If Y is a column vector, it must contain positive integer category numbers". I tried to make them categorical, bu this time I get "Creating an instance of the Abstract class 'categorical' is not allowed". The Matlab tutorial says that I keep them ordinal.